# How to resolve this error in weka?

Tags: weka

While giving input to ![weka][1] using my training set i get the **following error :**

> Wrong number of values .Read 12,expected 4, Read token [EOL] line 3.

**A sample data set :**

```
insert,into,(name.email.comment),values,('test'.'test1'.'test2')--,'anything','anything'),no

insert,into,(name.email),values,('parameter1'.'parameter2')--),'anything',no
```

Comment: Try reopening your file and replace the comma ( , ) with semicolon ( ; )

Comment: can we give null values for certain attributes in our data set ?? because select statements go up to 4 columns in CSV and insert statements go up to 12 columns..